# how to rotate text in a rich text box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox with text that i present to the user in a windows form.
the text it 
the user can not change the text (read only). the richtextbox is not editable.

How do i rotate the text to be vertical?

Comment: This is not possible. Why are you using a textbox control in the first place if the user can't edit the text?

Comment: so which control do you recomand?

Comment: You're going to have to create your own custom control that handles all of its own drawing. GDI+ supports this, exposed in managed code via the `Graphics` class.

Comment: You can use an image control and rotate it.  Look at this post http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/rimage.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can use message EM_SETPAGEROTATE. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)